# Codeigniter insert_id() function retrieve correctly the last insert id?

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert-id

I been programming  3~4 years ago, and I remember that in some 2005 php security book about the safety of using mysql_insert_id to retrieve the last_inser_id.

In the book says that if there is several request to the server at the same time (thousands), could make the retrieve of last_insert_id wrong, ending with user's id pointing to other users.

Now we are in 2013, what you guys have to says about this, and especially using codeigniter insert_id().

pd: I tried to find relevant info about my question in other places but I didnt found something concrete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whoever wrote that book is full of crap. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is specific to the connection, and the connection is specific to current invocation of the script. I can't think of a way to break this without re-writing some PHP source code after a night of heavy drinking.

*Maybe* if you're using persistent connections, and then *if* the last connection did an insert, and *then* you called `LAST_INSERT_ID()` before doing a successful insert yourself [you check your return values, *right?*], then *maybe* you *might* get a bad value. However, I have a very hard time imagining that this is possible.

So long as you're running `LAST_INSERT_ID()` immediately after the `INSERT` you just did it's always going to return the proper value.

Here's how you could break it if you really wanted:

```
$db_obj->insert('some data');
$db_obj->some_function_that_also_inserts_but_i_forgot_it_does_that('derp');
$id = $db_obj->last_insert_id();
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, I cant upvote your answer because of my reputation, But thank you really.

Comment: @JoseFaro click the checkbox to accept the answer, it's *way* better than an upvote.